# Smarty - String to Currency from comma to point to comma

Tags: type-conversion, smarty

i have the following string:

```
$betrag = 4,9
```

an want to convert this to a currency:

```
4,90 €
```

is there a better way as:

```
{$betrag|replace:",":"."|string_format:"%.2f"|replace:".":","} €
```

Comment: I think you note the better way. Or create a method for this if you need it in a lot of places.

Answer (score 1):

Good solution is to use smarty modifiers:

```
function smarty_modifier_num2front($string, $precision = 2)
{
   // here you can use your own filter by call some class (or direct php code)
   return \lib\Numeric::front($string, $precision);
}
```

Following function should be located in your smarty plugin directory and in this case named 'modifier.num2front.php'

In template you use this like that:

```
{$betrag|num2front}
```